# Opening a Fragment onclick of Notification Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, notifications, android-notifications

I have been recently working on Notifications in My android app.

As my Application have only 1 activity with some fragments..

So, to handle my one of the Button On the Notification so that it can 
Open a Fragment and call a method (or it can call a method which contains all my code including opening The fragment )

In course of this I am sucessfull in building a notification and with working button But with a limitation that the button can only be handled to open any activity

Here's my code of Notification , Please take a look in it and 
Please suggest how should I do it ..

```
 public int getNotification(View view, String Data) {

    // NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Context context = view.getContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Notification","1");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    //Intent for "Navigate" Button on Notification
    String lat = String.valueOf(dest.latitude);
    String lon = String.valueOf(dest.longitude);
    String format = "geo:0,0?q=" + lat + "," + lon + "Destination Point";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(format);
    Intent intentNavigate = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    PendingIntent pIntentNavigate = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intentNavigate, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getToast("API below 16 ...notification not supported");

    } else {
        //Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_car);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        //builder.setLargeIcon(icon);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icar);
        builder.setContentTitle("Car Rental Application");
        builder.setContentText(Data);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSound(soundUri);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_gps, "NAVIGATE ", pIntentNavigate);
        builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop, "STOP RIDE", pendingIntent);
        Notification notify = builder.build();

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notify);

    }

    return notificationID;
}

public void removeNotification() {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(
            notificationID);
    getToast("Notification Removed");
}
```

I have to Handle my 2nd Action in the Notification (STOP RIDE) which should call a function stopride()
(Please ask if further ref. needed)
Please help me making this possible for me ..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to  get your values from `getIntent()` in  `MapsActivity`
Now you are trying to invoke `MapsActivity` on "STOP RIDE" action with this intent -

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Notification","1");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

You can use the  same key "Notification" or add one more flag in this like -

```
  intent.putExtra("key_stop",true);
```

In `MapsActivity's onCreate()` you can instantiate your fragment by checking your flag -

```
    boolean stopFlag = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("key_stop",false);

    if(stopFlag){
      //Launch your fragment
    }
```

Hope this helps !!